# Show data(numbers) instead of pins on google map

Tags: google-maps

I want to show data (numbers) from database on the map, instead of just pointing the place and clicking on the pin to show data, I want it shown already where the pin is. I use this example to make the google map with pins: http://tips4php.net/2010/10/use-php-mysql-and-google-map-api-v3-for-displaying-data-on-map/

I cannot show images because I'm a new user, so here is an example of what I want to show on map, information about prices instead of usual pins: http://www.norc-imobiliare.ro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [dynamic icons](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons?hl=de#encoding) of the Image Charts -API. But this API is deprecated, it may(but must not) stop working in 2015.

The other options:

1. create an own serverside script that takes the strings(prices) as argument and delivers the desired image based on the input.
2. create a overlay  instead of a marker, it may contain any HTML. e.g. [infoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html) would be usable.

Comment: [Image-Charts-Example](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/r2dEv/) + [InfoBox-Example](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/G9Lgk/)